# why can I not install php mongodb driver on mac?

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, driver

Here is what I do:

1) I install driver in command:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongo
Password:
WARNING: "pecl/mongo" is deprecated in favor of "channel:///mongodb"
downloading mongo-1.6.12.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.6.12.tgz (209,252 bytes)
.............................................done: 209,252 bytes
118 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Build with Cyrus SASL (MongoDB Enterprise Authentication) support? [no] : 
building in /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootTF9cNk/mongo-1.6.12
running: /private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-mongo-sasl=no
running: make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
ERROR: `make' failed。
```

2) I make source code manually download code and unzip it

```
$ phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212

$ ./configure

$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 3):

Package https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo has been superseded by https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb. Install it as

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Comment: same error:
running: make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: sudo pecl install mongodb
downloading mongodb-1.1.2.tgz ...
Starting to download mongodb-1.1.2.tgz 
..............done: 642,582 bytes
349 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
building in /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootpqxu7v/mongodb-1.1.2
running: /private/tmp/pear/install/mongodb/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
running: make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: Apparently makefile was not created. Try to increase verbosity to check the cause:  `sudo pecl -v install mongodb`. You can use `-vvv` for more verbosity, but it will be a lot of data.